# Django no such table

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

In the development environment of a new Django project I have 2 apps and I am was running into issues of "no column named" exceptions. I ended up deleting the sqlite db and retried `python manage.py makemigrations` and `pyhon manage.py migrate` now I run into a new exception of no table exits. I can verify from the sqlite model that the table do not exits, but I did not receive any errors after deleting the database and rerun `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`

In models.py for my products app

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.db.models.fields import CharField
    from instructions.models import Instruction
    # Create your models here.
    
    class Product(models.Model):
        productName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        productDescription = models.TextField(blank=True)
        productPrice = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=0, default=0)
        productSubQuantity = models.IntegerField(default=1, blank=False)
        productAvailable = models.BooleanField(default = True)
        productCreated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
        productUpdated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
        productSlug = models.SlugField(max_length = 255, unique = True,
        help_text = "Unique text for url created from product name")
        productMetaKeywords = models.CharField("Meta keywords for SEO", max_length = 255,
        help_text ="Comma delimited words for SEO")
        productMetaDescription = models.CharField("Meta description", max_length = 255,
        help_text="Content for meta tag description")
        instruction = models.ForeignKey(Instruction, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = "instruction")
    
        class Meta:
            db_table = 'products'
            ordering = ['-productName']
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.productName
    
    class Image(models.Model):
        image = models.ImageField()
        imageMetaKeyWords = models.CharField("Meta keywords for SEO", max_length = 255,
        help_text = "Comma delimited words for SEO")
        imageMetaDescription = models.CharField("Meta description", max_length = 255,
        help_text = "Content for image meta tag description")
        defaultImage = models.BooleanField(default= False)
        product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="images")
```

In models.py in instructions app

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Instruction(models.Model):
    instructionName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    instructionEstimatedPreparationTime = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    instructionContent = models.TextField(blank = False)
    instructionVideoFilePath = models.FileField(blank = True, null = True)
    instructionVideoQRcode = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank = True, null = True)
```

In settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for dimsumbox project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.8.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-)4we8*9#lmu^+(x%k+&thxt8t0f=*m^f8h5xfba9wiwc6r2@ze'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'products',
    'instructions'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'dimsumbox.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'dimsumbox.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Error output when I entered the products from admin

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/products/product/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: products

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 616, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 232, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1697, in changelist_view
    cl = self.get_changelist_instance(request)
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 736, in get_changelist_instance
    return ChangeList(
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py", line 100, in __init__
    self.get_results(request)
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py", line 235, in get_results
    result_count = paginator.count
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py", line 97, in count
    return c()
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 412, in count
    return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 519, in get_count
    number = obj.get_aggregation(using, ['__count'])['__count']
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 504, in get_aggregation
    result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1175, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 423, in execute
(env) jianxiongwu@Jians-MacBook-Pro dimsumbox % python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
October 24, 2021 - 06:09:35
Django version 3.2.8, using settings 'dimsumbox.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[24/Oct/2021 06:09:40] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 10697
[24/Oct/2021 06:09:43] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5130
[24/Oct/2021 06:09:44] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5130
Internal Server Error: /admin/products/product/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: products

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 616, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 232, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1697, in changelist_view
    cl = self.get_changelist_instance(request)
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 736, in get_changelist_instance
    return ChangeList(
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py", line 100, in __init__
    self.get_results(request)
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py", line 235, in get_results
    result_count = paginator.count
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py", line 97, in count
    return c()
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 412, in count
    return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 519, in get_count
    number = obj.get_aggregation(using, ['__count'])['__count']
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 504, in get_aggregation
    result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1175, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/jianxiongwu/Documents/Python/Github/DimsumBox_website/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: products
[24/Oct/2021 06:09:46] "GET /admin/products/product/ HTTP/1.1" 500 170815
```

Comment: try `python manage.py makemigrations app` and `python manage.py migrate app` and also what is your app name ? I think you have added model name in `settings.py` file instead of app name.

Comment: this works! Why can't one just run python manage.py makemigrations as I did to begin with? Can you write this an answer to close this issue?

Comment: can you update you `views.py` file so that we can debug more clearly.

Comment: I haven't written anything in the views.py yet. It is only for the admin view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by Sunil Ghimire `python manage.py makemigrations app` followed by `python manage.py migrate app` solved this problem as for some strange reasons that I don't yet understand the `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` alone without the app did not work.

Answer (score 0):

May be migrations directory missing in app folder, that may be the reason. That why when we add app name at the end of makemigrations , it creates an migrations directory in app